# Port not being forwarded. What else do I need to do?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, xampp, web-hosting

I am trying to host website and a backend program on internet. So I set some virtual servers which are shown
[NAT virtual servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzwDk.png)

On the machine 192.168.1.5 I am running XAMPP server

[XAMPP screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvNYK.png)

Now when I try to access it using my public ip the page does not load, but on accessing it using 192.168.1.5 do works. when I try to access it using public ip It shows

[unloaded web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOcrK.png)

Is there something I am missing...

I have seen many previous asked questions but no solution seems to be working.. I tried accessing from outside my LAN, I ensured that I am getting a public ip, ensured the ports etc... PLEASE HELP

Comment: In order to answer this question, you must indicate, if you are behind enterprise NAT or not.  In order to determine this, when you view your IP address using the website of your choice, are you given a public IP address or a private IP address?

Comment: @Ramhound when I google 'my ip' i get 106.207.213.222 but when I open my router settings it shows
```
 WAN IP Address: 100.88.85.0 
Default Gateway: 100.88.0.1
Primary DNS: 203.153.41.28
Secondary DNS: 203.153.44.44
``` does this mean that my router has a private ip??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using Railtel Internet. They are providing your Private IP on your router via PPPOE. It means, no one can reach to you. You may ask railtel to do the following

1. Ask them to route a particular port to your router and then use that port for your server.
2. Ask them to provide you a static Public IP address and then define virtual server or DMZ on your main Router.